How can I remove the xmas tree effects from my keyboard
I just purchased a new Logitech G915.  On my previous mechanical Logitech, I was able to change the colour to a constant one of the intensity of my choosing.  I expected the new one to build on previous setup options, not replace them with idiocy.
But the new one is like a Xmas tree.

The lights always cycle through a rainbow of colours
And they change in intensity to boot

What I have done

Looked at the manual - it says to hold the Brightness key and press 0 to select cyan.

I don't really want cyan, but I could live with it.
After idling, it goes back to its Xmas tree effect


Googled

On Logitech feedback page, it suggested ghub software.  That's a waste of space.



I just want a calm steady colour to stay there permanently.   That is, I don't want distractions.

Because I bought it online, and I expected it to behave like the previous model, where you could turn it off.  Which is in my question.  I will highlight it.

To get the color to persist, you must load a profile to on-board memory. Since this is a one-time operation, the software can be uninstalled from Programs and Features after one use.

Download G-HUB.
Connect keyboard using Lightspeed.
In Settings, enable On-Board Memory mode to retain changes on the keyboard.
Create the desired keyboard lighting profile.
Check that the profile persists after reboot, and after disconnecting and reconnecting keyboard.
If you wish, you can now remove G-HUB, and the keyboard lighting should persist still.

Yep, I agree that some manufacturer's software is bloated... some webcam software is even larger and more ungainly. However, use it and lose it.
